# AndroidStudio にて ProGuard を実行した時のビルドエラー

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

AndroidStudio にて、 ProGuard を有効に設定し、

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

上記コマンドにてビルドを行ったところ、下記のようなエラーが発生します。

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: Can't read [[project_path]/app/android-support-v4.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)]
> >     (No such file or directory)

おそらく`android-support-v4` を含んだ複数のライブラリを利用しているため(後述)発生するエラーかと思うのですが、正しい解消法がわかっておりません。

上記に対して有効な解決手段をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら教えて下さい。

ちなみに、ライブラリには、`android-support-v7-appcompat` および `facebook` を使用しており、
ライブラリプロジェクトととして import しております。

`build.gradle` 抜粋:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':External:android-support-v7-appcompat')
    compile project(':External:facebook:facebook’)
    compile project(':External:PagerSlidingTabStrip:library')
}
```

Comment: proguardのタグを追加しました。

Comment: libsフォルダには何かjarが入っていますか？

Comment: もう一つsupport-v4を使用しているライブラリがもれていたので修正しました。
libsフォルダには、`AppTizerSDK_v1_2.jar`が入っています。

Answer (score 1):

```
./gradlew -q dependencies
```

で依存関係を確認してください。

おそらく、`com.android.support:support-v4` がいくつか見つかると思います。`com.android.support:appcompat-v7` に依存している `support-v4` のみ残し、その他をすべて exclude します。

```groovy
dependencies {
    compile project(':External:android-support-v7-appcompat')

    compile('com.example.foo.bar:xxx') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

もし、`libs` ディレクトリに `android-support-v4.jar` があれば削除します。

Comment: ご指摘のとおり修正してみましたが、以下のエラーが発生しています。


    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [[project_path/app/build/intermediates/classes-proguard/release/classes.jar] (Can't read [[project_path/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/App.External.PagerSlidingTabStrip/library/unspecified/libs/android-support-v4.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip entry [android-support-v4.jar:android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$1.class]))
`

Comment: PagerSlidingTabStrip をMavenを使って入れてみてはどうでしょうか。現在の PagerSlidingTabStrip を入れている `compile project(':External:PagerSlidingTabStrip:library')` の行を削除し、`compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'` を追加します。

Comment: @inon29 PagerSlidingTabStrip の libs ディレクトリに android-support-v4.jar があることが原因です。Mavenで管理しないのであればこのjarを削除してみると、どうなりますか？

Comment: 質問返して申し訳ありません。
PagerSlidingTabStripのプロジェクトのandroid-support-v4.jarを削除する場合ですが、PagerSlidingTabStrip内のライブラリ参照箇所については、どのように解決すればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @inon29 PagerSlidingTabStrip が参照する Support Library のことを忘れていました…。Gradle で依存している support-v4 のバージョンと同じjarを PagerSlidingTabStrip の libs ディレクトリに置けば動くかもしれませんが、Maven で管理するのが近道な気がします。